# appium 1.6 sendKeys to EditText Failed

Tags: java, android, mobile, automated-tests, appium

I am writing some java code using java - client of the appium. I successfully enter the page for inputting the text, however, after getting into the page, the input field are not responding.

Here is the structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
    <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout"  ]" resource-id="" instance="0">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout"  ]" resource-id="" instance="0">
            <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout"  4]" resource-id="android:id/content" instance="1">
                <android.webkit.WebView index="0" text="" class="android.webkit.WebView"  4]" resource-id="" instance="0">
                    <android.webkit.WebView index="0" text="" class="android.webkit.WebView"  content-desc="Home"  focused="true" scrollable="true" 4]" resource-id="" instance="1">
                        <android.widget.Button index="0" text="" class="android.widget.Button"  content-desc="纬 " checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  " resource-id="" instance="0"/>
                    <android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Sign Up Page" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 36]" resource-id="" instance="0"/>
                <android.view.View index="2" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Home" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 6]" resource-id="" instance="1"/>
            <android.widget.Button index="3" text="" class="android.widget.Button"  content-desc="sign up " checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  48]" resource-id="" instance="1"/>
        <android.widget.Button index="4" text="" class="android.widget.Button"  content-desc=" Clean Time Logs " checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  8]" resource-id="" instance="2"/>
        <android.view.View index="5" text="" class="android.view.View"  scrollable="true" 84]" resource-id="" instance="2">
    <android.widget.Image index="0" text="" class="android.widget.Image"  content-desc="PEGI_gambling" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 78]" resource-id="" instance="0"/>
    <android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Welcome!" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 342]" resource-id="" instance="3"/>
    <android.view.View index="2" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="anonymous" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 404]" resource-id="" instance="4"/>
    <android.view.View index="3" text="" class="android.view.View"  90]" resource-id="" instance="5">
        <android.widget.Image index="0" text="" class="android.widget.Image"  content-desc="white-dove" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 88]" resource-id="" instance="1"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="4" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="This is the home page of the mobile app. The right hand most button is for switching page. Bottom is the time logs of clicking button or changing the views. The button at the subheader is used for cleaning all time logs." checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 184]" resource-id="" instance="6"/>
<android.view.View index="5" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="*The Like, Comment are fake." checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 1184]" resource-id="" instance="7"/>
<android.view.View index="6" text="" class="android.view.View"  1184]" resource-id="" instance="8">
    <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Like" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  1184]" resource-id="" instance="9"/>
    <android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Comment" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,1184]" resource-id="" instance="10"/>
</android.view.View>
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="6" text="" class="android.view.View"  scrollable="true" 1184]" resource-id="" instance="11">
    <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  1184]" resource-id="" instance="12">
        <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Account &amp; Personal Info" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 316]" resource-id="" instance="13"/>
        <android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View"  430]" resource-id="" instance="14">
            <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Username" 418]" resource-id="_label-0" instance="15">
                <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Username" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 404]" resource-id="" instance="16"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.widget.EditText index="1" text="" class="android.widget.EditText"  content-desc="e.g. woody" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,408]" resource-id="" instance="0"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="2" text="" class="android.view.View"  544]" resource-id="" instance="17">
    <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Email" 532]" resource-id="_label-1" instance="18">
        <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Email" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 518]" resource-id="" instance="19"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.widget.EditText index="1" text="" class="android.widget.EditText"  content-desc="1232@gmail.com" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,522]" resource-id="" instance="1"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="3" text="" class="android.view.View"  658]" resource-id="" instance="20">
    <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Password" 646]" resource-id="_label-2" instance="21">
        <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Password" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 632]" resource-id="" instance="22"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.widget.EditText NAF="true" index="1" text="" class="android.widget.EditText"  checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,636]" resource-id="" instance="2"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="4" text="" class="android.view.View"  772]" resource-id="" instance="23">
    <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Birthday" 760]" resource-id="_label-3" instance="24">
        <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Birthday" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 746]" resource-id="" instance="25"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.widget.Spinner NAF="true" index="1" text="" class="android.widget.Spinner"  checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,750]" resource-id="" instance="0"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="5" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Interest" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 860]" resource-id="" instance="26"/>
<android.view.View index="6" text="" class="android.view.View"  976]" resource-id="" instance="27">
    <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Description" 964]" resource-id="_label-4" instance="28">
        <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="Description" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 950]" resource-id="" instance="29"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.widget.EditText NAF="true" index="1" text="" class="android.widget.EditText"  checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,964]" resource-id="" instance="3"/>
</android.view.View>
<android.widget.Button index="7" text="" class="android.widget.Button"  content-desc="Submit " checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,1142]" resource-id="" instance="3"/>
<android.widget.Button index="8" text="" class="android.widget.Button"  content-desc="Reset " checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true"  ,1184]" resource-id="" instance="4"/>
</android.view.View>
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="7" text="" class="android.view.View"  scrollable="true" 184]" resource-id="" instance="30">
    <android.view.View index="0" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="[ 07:13:10.193 ] Page is loaded." checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 184]" resource-id="" instance="31"/>
    <android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View"  content-desc="[ 07:13:10.019 ] Button is clicked." checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" 184]" resource-id="" instance="32"/>
</android.view.View>
</android.webkit.WebView>
</android.webkit.WebView>
</android.widget.FrameLayout>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
<android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View"   resource-id="android:id/statusBarBackground" instance="33"/>
<android.view.View index="2" text="" class="android.view.View"  280]" resource-id="android:id/navigationBarBackground" instance="34"/>
</android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

and the code:

```
     WebElement username = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.webkit.WebView[@content-desc='Sign Up Page']/android.view.View[@index='4']/android.view.View[@index='0']/android.view.View[@index='1']/android.widget.EditText[@index='1']");
     username.click();
     username.sendKeys("appium_username");
```

I want to send key to the input field to the EditText{e.g. woody} element. How can I do that?

The following is the action approach I wrote after reading Lyle's comment:

```
         driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@index='1']").click();

     Actions action = new Actions(driver);

     action.click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.webkit.WebView[@content-desc='Sign Up Page']/android.view.View[@index='4']/"
                + "android.view.View[@index='0']/android.view.View[@index='1']/android.widget.EditText[@index='1']")));

     action.sendKeys("appium_test");
```

I get the following problem and I am not exactly knowing what's going on:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

By my observation, there is no keyboard shown after the program run through these lines of code

Comment: are you getting username ?

Comment: no. I am getting the EditText (which is set to be an input field). The content-desc='Username' is just a label

Answer (score 0):

```
        //---try using Actions

        Actions typeText = new Actions(Driver);

        typeText.click(xpath);
        typeText.sendKeys(textToSend); 
        typeText.perform();
```

Comment: Does the Actions class mean the TouchAction or MultiAction Class?

Comment: Niether of the two. Just use Actions action = new Actions(Driver);

Comment: I get
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Please provide a few words of explanation for the code you posted (what's going on, which components communicate, why does it work, etc.)

Comment: I have added an extension for the code I tried in this Actions approach. When I run it, there is no response showing the input field has been clicked(in the android phone, there should be keyboard coming up after clicking at the input field).

Comment: You'll have to get the java client jar file for Appium, so that Actions Class can work

Comment: Thanks, Lyle. I have already been using the Actions Class, but it didn't work. I would like to ask also would the windows version affect, 'cause I am using windows 8.1.

Comment: xpath: //android.webkit.WebView[@content-desc='Sign Up Page'] could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear text field than send key again

```
typeText.clear();
typeText.sendKeys(xpath);
```