# Appium - When do we use touch action? Could I have actual example for inputing text with it?

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium

I would like to ask when do  we use touch action in Appium. I also want to ask: could we use touch action to tap/press the android.widget.EditText element and sendKeys to it. Could I have an workable example to test it?

Comment: is below solution working?

Comment: Not exactly. I could find a button to click, however there is other's problem, I can't sendKeys to a textField: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271992/appium-1-6-sendkeys-to-edittext-failed
I can get the keyboard, but I can't sendKeys because the elements are never be clicked.

Comment: Can you use last two lines of code in the below answer? That should resolve your problem. Don't send keys directly to element. Just click on that and then use driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("textToBeTyped");

Comment: There does an element click, but not on the element I choose. After all the testing, I find that it directly click using the driver, but not by the xpath

Comment: driver finds the element using xpath only and then clicks.

Answer (score 2):

We use touch action whenever we want to **click/tap** on the particular element on the device.

**For Clicking**

You can use touch action for EditText element as bewlow :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your element xpath/id")).click();
```

**For Typing**

Also, You can use sendKeys for EditText Element as below :
This internal clicks on the element, clears the text and types the string that you are sending.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your element xpath/id")).sendKeys("textToBeTyped");
```

**OR**

You can click and send keys separately without clearing the existing text inside the text element as below :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your element xpath/id")).click();
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(textToBeTyped);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1.public void tap(int fingers, int x, int y, int duration) {
        appiumDriver.tap(fingers, x, y, duration);
    }

2. public   void swipe(int startx, int starty, int endx,int endy,int duration)
    {
        TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
        System.out.println(startx+" "+starty);
        System.out.println("Entering swipe");

            System.out.println("Swipe from "+startx +" " +starty +"to" +endx +" " +endy );
            touchAction.press(startx, starty).waitAction(duration).moveTo(endx,endy).release().perform();
    }

3. public void longClick(String element, int index, int clickCount, int X, int Y) {
    WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));

        TouchAction Action = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
        Action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();

    }

4. public void drag( String element, int index, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        TouchAction drag=new TouchAction(appiumDriver);

        int startX=webElement.getLocation().getX();
        int startY=webElement.getLocation().getY();

        System.out.println("startX: "+startX+" startY: "+startY);
        drag.press(startX,startY).moveTo(xOffset,yOffset).release().perform();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**In all the appium client libraries, touch objects are created and are given a chain of events**. First you must initialize TouchAction ovbject with your webdriver and then chain your steps in order to perform action. You can demonstrate variety of gestures such as :

- Tap
- press(Long,Short)
- Swipe (from coordinate a to b)
- perform multi touch actions

You can do it with given parameters such as duration per action, wait settings, set releasing and more.

**examples:**

in order to press an element with coordinates :

```
new TouchAction(driverObject).tap(PointOption.point(x,y)).perform();
```

or:

```
new TouchAction(driverObject).press(PointOption.point(x,y)).perform();
```

in order to swipe element from pointA to pointB with Z duration of millis

```
//wait parameters for duration purposes
WaitOptions waitOptions = new WaitOptions();
waitOptions.withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(millis));

//The action
new TouchAction(driverObject).longPress.press(fromPoint)
                .waitAction(waitOptions).moveTo(toPoint).release().perform();
```